# To Iterate dataframe to check the unit and convert the units .TypeError: tuple indices must be integers or slices, not str

Tags: python, pandas, list, dataframe, typeerror

I am trying to check the unit in my dataset but gettingthis error, is anybody can help me , in this problem

```
df=pd.read_csv("/content/unit_checkv1.csv")

UNITS ={"G/HA":0.001,"ML/100KG":0.001}

for row in df.iterrows():
  unit_factor, unit_target = UNITS[row["DOSAGE_UNIT"]]
  if unit_factor:
    row["DOSAGE"] = (
    row["DOSAGE"] * unit_factor
    if row["DOSAGE"] is not None
    else None
  )
row["DOSAGE_UNIT"] = unit_target
```

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow. Please take the time to read this post on [how to provide a great pandas example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20109391/how-to-make-good-reproducible-pandas-examples) as well as how to provide a [minimal, complete, and verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and revise your question accordingly. These tips on [how to ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) may also be useful.

Comment: Hard to know what need, maybe `df['NEW'] = df["DOSAGE_UNIT"].map(UNITS) * df['DOSAGE']` ?

Comment: NEWi am gettinh nan values when i doing it.
0      NaN
1      NaN
3      NaN
4      NaN
6      NaN
...    ...
24287  NaN
24288  NaN
24289  NaN
24290  NaN
24291  NaN

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [`Series.map`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.map.html) instead your solution:

```
df['NEW'] = df["DOSAGE_UNIT"].map(UNITS) * df['DOSAGE']
```

Comment: i am gettinh nan values when i doing it.NEW
0      NaN
1      NaN
3      NaN
4      NaN
6      NaN
...    ...
24287  NaN
24288  NaN
24289  NaN
24290  NaN
24291  NaN